# Map elements in two lists and add one to the other list

Tags: python, list, comparison

Sorry if the title is a little confusing. I have two files, file1 and file2 both with many columns. I need to find common elements in a certain column, if they match, the whole line from file1 should be added to the matched line in file2:

e.g.:

```
file1.txt:
[a,b,c],
[x,e,y],
...

file2.txt:
[d,e,f],
[s,p,z],
...
```

Note, here just the element "e" matches, the result should (in a new file, but with all of the information in file2.txt) be:

```
newfile.txt:
[d,e,f],[x,e,y],
[s,p,z]
```

...

My idea:

```
output = open('file2.txt', 'w')
for f in variants:
    add = ""
    if f[0] in sources:
        add = ???
    output.write("\t".join(f) + add + "\n")
output.close()
```

"variants" contains the list from file1.txt, I don't really understand how to add the rest of the information from file1.txt to the matching line in file2.txt, any help please!

Comment: Why not use just simple text `a, b, c` instead of `[a,b,c]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def parse_data(line):
    # Returns a list of values from line of text.
    return line[1:-2].split(',')

with open('newfile.txt', 'wb') as new_file, open('file1.txt', 'rb') as f1, open('file2.txt', 'rb') as f2:
    mapping = defaultdict(list)
    # Zero-based indexing.
    CERTAIN_COLUMN = 1
    for line in f1:
        # Remove new-lines and get comma-separated values.
        line = line.strip()
        columns = parse_data(line)
        mapping[columns[CERTAIN_COLUMN]].append(line)

    for line in f2:
        line = line.strip()
        columns = parse_data(line)
        for matched in mapping[columns[CERTAIN_COLUMN]]:
            new_file.write('{},{},\n'.format(matched, line))
```

The first loop populates the dict with `search_criteria` -> `matched rows` mapping, i.e `e` -> `['[x,e,y]']`.

The second loop prints all entries that meet the search criteria for each line of `file2.txt`